# Вставка значения или обновления для строки

Tags: mysql

Есть ли такой вид запроса, который, или изменяет строку в базе, или если не находит ее - создает новую.

P.S Я понимаю, что можно сделать 2 запросами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть даже два варианта: REPLACE и INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Первый фактически делает DELETE, затем INSERT. А второй вариант буквально то, о чем вы спрашиваете.